# PowerShell 7: How can I use a previous parameter to influence a current parameter with Register-ArgumentCompleter for autocompletion?

Tags: powershell, autocomplete, powershell-7.0

I have a basic powershell function that benefits from autocompletion, but I cannot figure out how to use a previous parameter value (in this case call it `show`) be used to construct the path to lookup another auto completed value (`shot`).

```
$showScriptBlock = {
    param($commandName,$parameterName,$stringMatch)

    Get-ChildItem -Path "\\serverpath\projects\$stringMatch*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
}

$shotScriptBlock = {
    param($commandName,$parameterName,$stringMatch,$commandAst,$fakeBoundParameters)

    Get-ChildItem -Path "\\serverpath\projects\$show\shots\$stringMatch*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
}


Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName my-env -ParameterName show -ScriptBlock $showScriptBlock
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName my-env -ParameterName shot -ScriptBlock $shotScriptBlock
```

This works easily for `shot`.

Obviously `$show` cannot be used in `$shotScriptBlock`, but what might I do to get that $show value to influence the $shot value script block?

Please keep in mind the position of the arguments could change, but shot would always be specified after show:

my-env -someParm someValue -show myShow -shot myShot

Comment: In principle you can access the variable $show from the scriptblock ny using [ref]$show inside your scriptblock: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: But I think you better go with named parameters and provide $show as parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Why not simply using a combined "`$ShowShotScriptBlock`" with a condition `if ($parameterName -eq 'Show') { ...` ?

Comment: @Toni I dont understand what you mean by going with named paramaters, since Register-ArgumentCompleter passes a predefined set of parameters that I thought were positional to script block.  Can you help with an example of how its possible for scriptblock to reference two seperate parameters?  Register-ArgumentCompleter docs don't show this at all.

Comment: @iRon I don't see how that could work since 2 parameters are required simultaneously, and Register-ArgumentCompleter only passes one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is I must use `$fakeBoundParameters`.  This works...

```
$shotScriptBlock = {
    param($commandName,$parameterName,$stringMatch,$commandAst,$fakeBoundParameters)
    if ($fakeBoundParameters.ContainsKey("show")) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path "\\serverpath\projects\$($fakeBoundParameters.show)\shots\$stringMatch*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    } else {
        return @()
    }
}
```